# How do we find the centripetal forces of 3 planets revolving around a point given that they have the same mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets, centripetal-force

Let's say we have three planets revolving around a point. We know that the force of gravity acting on all of these planets can be taken from $g = G{m_1m_2 \over r^2}$. We can derive the velocity of these planets' revolutions through Centripetal force. How do we go about doing that?

Comment: Three planets will not form a stable orbit of each other at 120degrees intervals. The motion of three planets without other influence is a problem called "the three body problem" which has no known symbolic solution. Unless you add more constraints, like a central mass such as a star, differing radii, the neglection of planet-to-planet interactions to change the problem.

Comment: $g\neq G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$ which you write that is force rather than gravitational acceleration. $g=\frac{GM}{r^2}$

Comment: @JMLCarter It is true that the general three-body problem does not have an explicit analytic solution. However, some restricted versions may have. The case of three objects of equal mass on an equilateral triangle configuration is one. There is no need for a central mass.

Comment: Forces are represented by vectors. What is the difficulty of evaluating the sum of two vectors to get the force on one of the three bodies?

Comment: @GiorgioP The point I am making is that such a configuration is not stable. Inevitable pertubations will degrade it. The stable lagrange points are at (aprox) 60 degrees. An example of a solution that is transient in the context of astronomy.

Comment: @JMLCarter I know that the dynamic configuration with three bodies of equal mass moving as the vertices of an equilateral triangle is unstable. But this is clearly a homework where the stability conditions do not enter into play and the purpose is to do an exercise on force composition and a constant circular motion.

Answer (score 0):

[For fun:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem#General_solution)

[image: 3b]

The three body problem in general has to be solved numerically. The mathematical setup is [given here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem#Mathematical_description)